# Can I download Raspbian update packages on a Redhat Linux Server?

Tags: raspbian, linux

I have a Redhat Linux Server that I'm running and I'm trying to create a update repository for Raspberry Pis, is it possible to download the update packages to my Redhat server, and if so, how?

Comment: Why don't you just mirror http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ and sync it daily?  I don't think there's anything more to it than what you see there (the package manager on the client uses http exclusively AFAICT).  You can then use your repo in place of it in apt sources as per Ingo's answer to your previous question.

Comment: Thank you @goldilocks, I will give this a shot, do you have a link how I would go about mirroring that site?

Comment: No.  Probably a better question for our larger sibling site, [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Cloned [my previous answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/99957/79866).

Raspbian is a derivate from Debian and it also uses Debians infrastructure. As far as I understand you want to setup your own package repository like that one used by Raspbian and Debian. First of all: the used repositories are configured in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and in files in directory `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`. On Raspbian there are two files by default:

```
rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi

rpi ~$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

You can browse the repositories with http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ and with http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/

The former repository is mainly the Debian repository http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ just compiled for armhf. The latter repository is from the Raspberry Pi Foundation and contains specific software to run the Raspberry Pi hardware, e.g. the kernel, firmware and drivers. This could be an example for your setup.

I do not have made a Debian repository before so I can give only some pointers. Here I have fond an entry for a [Debian Repository Setup](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianRepository/Setup). You also can google for "*how to make a debian repository*".

Comment: Yes that's correct I'd like to set up my own package repository, however I will be setting up the package repository on a Redhat Linux server, are the infrastructures compatible? @Ingo

Comment: @Jbro1945 I don't know. Redhat uses its own package management system with rpm packages. But it should be possible to install foreign software from Debian by hand and run it.

Comment: I don't think the OP needs to install any .deb packages on the RH server (which is potentially possible, but requires you pull the packages apart and check library linkage, etc.) -- the software from that setup page such as "Dak" are fetched from git repos.  WRT "the infrastructures", the infrastucture in this case is an HTTP(S) service, which is platform agnositic.